# separating string between commas into an array in c

Tags: c

I want to split a string into several strings stored in an array (of strings). I tried to use `strtok_r`, but I couldn't get that to work. So I tried doing it using this code:

```c
int r=0;
int c=0;
for (int e=0;buf2[e]!=NULL;e++) {
    if (buf2[e]!=",") {
        monsters[i].types[c][r] = buf2[e];
        r++;
    } else {
        r=0;
        c++;
    }
}
```

`buf2` is the string I'm splitting, `monsters[i].types[c]` is the array of strings I'm splitting it into. When I do this, it gives me:

```
In file included from main.c:7:0:
resource.h: In function ‘main’:
resource.h:97:22: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
  for (int e=0;buf2[e]!=NULL;e++) {
                      ^
resource.h:98:14: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
   if (buf2[e]!=",") {
              ^
```

I tried putting the ascii values instead of `NULL` & `","`, and it didn't give me any warnings, but it didn't work. And is there any way to include the two extra variable declarations before the `for` into the for loop, next to the other int declaration?

**Edit:**

So I tried using `strtok`, this is my code:

```c
buf3 = strtok(buf2,",");
strcpy(monsters[i].types[0],buf3);
for (int e=1;buf3!=NULL;e++) {
    buf3 = strtok(NULL,",");
    strcpy(monsters[i].types[e],buf3);
}
```

This gives me a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

**ReEdit:**

OK, so I just needed to switch the order of setting `buf3` & the `strcpy`:

```c
buf3 = strtok(buf2,",");
for (int e=0;buf3!=NULL;e++) {
    strcpy(monsters[i].types[e],buf3);
    buf3 = strtok(NULL,",");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, character constant syntax in C language uses single quotation marks: `','`, not `","`.

Secondly, don't compare character values to `NULL`. `NULL` is reserved to pointer contexts. Terminating zero character can be described as `'\0'` or simply as `0`.

Thirdly, there are dedicated library functions specifically designed to simplify this task, like `strtok`. I don't know though whether you can use them.

As for variable declarations, yes, you can put them all in `for` as long as they all have the same type

```
for (int e = 0, r = 0, c = 0; ...
```

Note though that variables declared in this way will not be available after `for`. And you will definitely need your `c` after this `for`.

Comment: OK, I didn't realize that strtok could do that much. The thing I was wondering about was, why do they do `strtok(NULL, delim)` in all the examples I see for all the times they use it after the first one?

Answer (score 0):

```
char kDelimiter = ',';
char* start = my_string;
char* end = my_string;
char *substrings[SUBSTRINGS_MAX_NUM];
uint32_t substring_idx = 0;
uint32_t finished = 0; /* false */
do {
    end = strchr(start, kDelimiter);
    if (!end) {
        end = my_string + strlen(my_string);
        finished = 1; /* true */
    }
    ssize_t substring_len = end - start;
    substrings[substring_idx] = NULL;
    substrings[substring_idx] = malloc(substring_len + 1);
    if (!substrings[substring_idx]) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not allocate space for substring!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    memcpy(substrings[substring_idx], start, end - start);
    substrings[substring_idx] + (end - start) = '\0';
    start = end + 1;
    substring_idx++;
} while (!finished);
```